# Is $x_0^4+x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4-ax_0x_1x_2x_3$ irreducible for every $a \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I'm trying to solve the problem *Sec. 2 - 1.16* in Shafarevich's book Basic Algebraic Geometry, vol. 1, second ed. My attempt is to use the previous exercise *Sec. 2 - 1.12.* So I only need to show that the polynomial $x_0^4+x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4 - a x_0x_1x_2x_3$ is irreducible for every value of $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and compute the common roots of the polynomial and the partial derivatives.

My problem is to show that the polynomial is irreducible. I've found the following question in the MSE site related with the problem:

[Does $x_0^4+x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4 - a x_1x_2x_3x_4$ really define a surface?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172701/does-x-04x-14x-24x-34-ax-1x-2x-3x-4-really-define-a-surface/3172703#3172703)

In an answer, a user says that the irreducibility of the polynomial follows from an expression given there. What is he referring to? I've never seen something similar to this while proving that a polynomial is irreducible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: He is just saying that since the polynomial is $F_a(x_0, x_1,x_2,x_3) = P(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$, showing that $F_a$ is irreducible is the same as showing that $P$ is irreducible. However I did not see how this makes easier or even "clear".

Comment: @AlanMuniz Could you give me a reference for this result? I think that with your observation it is easy to solve my problem. Consider the polynomial $P \in \mathbb{C}[e_1,e_2,e_4][e_3]$ and since it is primitive the polynomial will be irreducible only if it is in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}(e_1,e_2,e_4)[e_3]$ and this is easy since in the variable $e_3$ $P$ is linear. Correct me if I'm wrong please. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. If $P= e_4 = x_0x_1x_2x_3$,  $F$ is reducible. If $F$ is irreducible then $P$ is irreducible. But the converse does not hold.

Comment: @AlanMuniz The theorem is no true in our case? Where can I find this theorem or similar? Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is no theorem it is just a remark. I don't know if it is stated explicitly anywhere.

Comment: The user in question has updated their post with more reasoning, and I believe this now qualifies as a duplicate of that post.